# local variable 'response_data' referenced before assignment, form works for one page but now that I try to use that form again this error pops up

Tags: python, django

I have a comment form that works fine. so I've decided to adopt this comment form to another page in my web. but local variable 'response_data' referenced before assignment shows up

this is my traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/comments/views.py" in comment_create_view
  49.           return JsonResponse(response_data)

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /comment/create/
Exception Value: local variable 'response_data' referenced before assignment
```

I believe the traceback is telling me that the form has some syntax error, which I don't understand because same form works for other page.

currently I have

```
@login_required
def comment_thread(request, id):

    comment = Comment.objects.get(id=id)
    form = CommentForm()
    context = {
    "form": form,
    "comment": comment,
    }
    return render(request, "comments/comment_thread.html", context)


in forms.py
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder": "leave"})
    )
    #hidden_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, hidden_data=None, data=None, files=None, **kwargs):
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(data, files, kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'leave', css_class='btn btn-default'))
        if hidden_data:
            self.helper.add_input(Hidden('post_id', hidden_data['post_id']))
            self.helper.add_input(Hidden('origin_path', hidden_data['origin_path']))
            if hidden_data.get('parent_id', None):
                self.helper.add_input(Hidden('parent_id', hidden_data['parent_id']))


In html


      <form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
                    <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
                    {% crispy form form.helper %}
                    <!-- <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Add reply'/> -->
                    </form>
```

this is my part of comment create view

```
@csrf_exempt
def comment_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            response_dat = {"code":400,"message":"Post does not exists"}
            return JsonResponse(response_data)


        parent_comment = None
        if parent_id is not None:
            try:
                parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            except:
                parent_comment = None

            if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
                post = parent_comment.post

        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            if parent_comment is not None:
                # parent comments exists
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post,
                    parent=parent_comment
                    )
                affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()
                notify.send(MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    action=new_comment,
                    target=parent_comment, 
                    recipient=parent_comment.user, 
                    affected_users=affected_users,
                    verb='leave')
                hidden_data = {
                    "post_id" : post.id,
                    "origin_path" : request.get_full_path,
                    "parent_id" : parent_comment.id
                }
                comment_form = CommentForm(hidden_data=hidden_data)
                html = render_to_string('main/child_comment.html', {'comment': [new_comment], 
                                        'user': request.user, 
                                        'comment_form':comment_form})
                response_data = {"status":200, "message":"comment_stored", 
                                                "comment":html, 
                                                'parent': True, 
                                                'parent_id': parent_comment.id,
                                                'comment_count': parent_comment.comment_count()}
                return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

in the post page it works fine, for that I have it like this

def post(request, slug):

```
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
    post.save()      # and save it
    profile = post.moderator
    #path = request.get_full_path()
    #comments = Comment.objects.filter(path=path)
    comments_count = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).count()
    comments = post.commented_post.all()
    for c in comments:
            c.get_children()
    hidden_data = {
                "post_id" : post.id,
                "origin_path" : request.get_full_path,
                "parent_id" : None
            }
    comment_form = CommentForm(hidden_data=hidden_data) 
    context_dict = {

        'comments' : comments,
        'comment_form':comment_form,
        'comments_count':comments_count,
        'profile' :profile,

    }
    return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you missspelled response_data as response_dat when you assigned it a value.

```
   try:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    except:
        response_dat = {"code":400,"message":"Post does not exists"}
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

should be

```
   try:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    except:
        response_data = {"code":400,"message":"Post does not exists"}
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Comment: ah -I see you added dat-a....my mistake but i still get local variable 'response_data' referenced before assignment

Comment: Do you still get the same error?  The original one is at line 49 in your code:

File "/comments/views.py" in comment_create_view
  49.           return JsonResponse(response_data)

If so, what's the  code where the error happens?